# Web service in iphone

Tags: iphone, web-services, string

i have a webservice and implementing that ,but when i get the array from this weservice its showing characters like   this     
  line brake in some keys.
I am trying to replace that with stringbyreplacing occurance of string but nothing happens.
Could anyone help me for this to replace this type of characters,show that when u want to show that data it don't contain this type of character.I am new to iphone development please help me

thanks

Comment: I recommend you mention what language/s you use..

Comment: @Oren A - from context it clearly is Objective-C

Comment: Yes that is Objective-C.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hard to help without seeing the code, but I guess you are calling `stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:withString:`, but not assigning the result back to a variable. Notice how this method returns a new object, but does not change the callee.

If you want to remove newlines, I suggest you use `stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:`:

```
key = [key stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet  newlineCharacterSet]];
```

Comment: Yes you are right bro i did the same thing as you mentioned,thats why it was not working.Well thanks dear for helping me.Hope to help me in the future as well.I am new to iphone development.